# AJAX futures drag and drop, potential bug with Chrome

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, drag-and-drop

Possible bug with AJAX futures drag and drop functionality in chrome:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function pageLoad() {
            var source1 = new Custom.UI.ColorDragSourceBehavior($get("1"), "1");
            source1.initialize();
            var source2 = new Custom.UI.ColorDragSourceBehavior($get("2"), "2");
            source2.initialize();
      }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div style="width:200%;">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
            <Scripts>
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="PreviewScript.js" Assembly="Microsoft.Web.Preview" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="PreviewDragDrop.js" Assembly="Microsoft.Web.Preview" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/ColorDragDrop.js" />
            </Scripts>
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <div id="1" style="float:left; width:30px; height:30px; background-color:Blue;">Left</div>
        <div id="2" style="float:right;width:30px; height:30px; background-color:Blue;">Right</div>
    </div>    
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

ColorDragDrop.js is available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135985.aspx):

Scroll to right and click on right division and the window auto scrolls back to the left.

There are a couple of mentions of this on the web but no solutions so I thought I'd ask here. I'm under a tight deadline and would rather not have to re-implement the drag and drop using jQuery or similar so any help gratefully received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a 3 line hack here:

http://www.targetprocess.com/agileproductblog/2009/03/aspnet-20-ajax-safari-and-scroll-offset.html

```
if (Sys.Browser.agent === Sys.Browser.Safari) {
    Sys.Preview.UI.DragDropManager._getInstance().getScrollOffset =
                Sys.Preview.UI.IEDragDropManager.prototype.getScrollOffset
    Sys.Preview.UI.DragDropManager._getInstance()._autoScroll = function() { }
}
```

works for safari and chrome.